# Help defining custom CRS in QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to use [EPSG:4479](http://epsg.io/4479) in QGIS.

1) If I search for EPSG:4479, it returns a "Imported from GDAL" EPSG:4479, but it does not work. At the console, the following message is displayed:

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 4479 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
```

It should not be a problem, because I can always add a new CRS. But...

2) I tried to define a new CRS in QGIS 2.2, without success.

I go to Settings -> Custom CRS... and fill the new CRS with:
Name: China Geodetic Coordinate System 2000
Parameters: +proj=geocent +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs

[image: Custom CRS definition]

These parameters are copy and pasted from [EPSG:4479](http://epsg.io/4479).

I can use the calculator at the botton to test the coordinate transformation, and it works.

But when I try to save the new CRS, it complains with the message: **The proj4 definition is not valid**.

[image: Error reporting invalid proj4 definition]

What am I doing wrong?

There is a [quite similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88918/add-custom-crs-2-2-0-valmiera) around, but not answered. But I'm not using a custom proj4 library.

I'm using QGIS 2.2, PROJ.4 Version 470, on top of the OSGeo Live 7.9.

**The same proj4 string works in PostGIS**. I am able to do:

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 4479, 'EPSG', 4479, '+proj=geocent +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ', 'GEOCCS["China Geodetic Coordinate System 2000",DATUM["China_2000",SPHEROID["CGCS2000",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1043"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Geocentric X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4479"]]');

select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Makepoint(114,30), 4326), 4479));
```

It returns the expected result:

```
"POINT(-2248544.5475367 5050313.74152924)"
```

Comment: How do you invoke the first error message?

Comment: To see the error reported, I started qgis from the command line. When I change to EPSG:4479, the error is reported on the console.
I am not able to use EPSG:4479 in QGIS.

Comment: Strangely I do not get that message. But it does not reproject layers with other CRS on-the-fly. BTW QGIS 2.2 on Windows comes with Proj 4.8.0. Not sure if you are missing something essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem saving the outline of China in EPSG:4479, and setting the project CRS to that:

[image]

Since this is a geocentric CRS, you really need all three coordinates, while QGIS usually works 2-dimensional. That might be a reason why some operations may fail.

The geocent projection is not listed by `proj -lp` in a terminal window, but proj is able to convert the coordinates, while the inverse conversion returns wrong values. cs2cs does it both ways.

Comment: Thank you @Andre. You are absolutely right! The _geocent_ projection is not available in `proj`. Probably that is why QGIS complains.