# Seeking algorithm for transforming from CGCS2000 to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, algorithm, china

Is there an algorithm that supports transforming from CGCS2000 coordinate to WGS84 coordinate?

CGCS2000 is China Geodetic Coordinate System 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [spatialreference.org, CGCS2000](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7408/) should be

```
 +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs
```

The usual approach is to add this definition as a custom CRS if you cannot find it in the default CRS list of QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

The EPSG registry lists two versions of CGCS2000:

`EPSG:4479` uses a 3-dimensional cartesian coordinate system based on the Earth's center
`EPSG:4480` uses Latitude, Longitude and ellipsoidal height.

For the first one, see [Help defining custom CRS in QGIS 2.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95729/help-defining-custom-crs-in-qgis-2-2) how to use it in QGIS and the limitations of that CRS.

For the second one, you can use the projection string that underdark suggested.